# Somehow toggled relative-only numbering from hybrid numbering in Vim

Tags: vim, line-numbers

Well, I was messing about in Vim experimenting with new (to me) commands, as I'm just learning my way around, and when I was using `gt`and `gT` to bounce between tabs, I somehow did something to switch my line numbering. I've been using hybrid line numbering, with the current line's absolute number showing and all others relative, but now (on just the one tab, mind) it's all relative, with a '0' on the current line. Also, using `gt` or `gT` on just that one tab seems to hang up unless I hit ESC.

Any ideas on what I did and how to fix it would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd check the output of `:map` to see what else might be conflicting with your tab switching mappings.  Normally to set hybrid numbering you must `:set number` and `:set relativenumber`, but if you have pure relative numbers, you must have gotten `:set nonumber` somehow.

Comment: Nice, thanks! I'm still not sure how it happened that I turned absolute line numbering off, but I was able to turn it back on, and I no longer hang when switching tabs. Cheers!

Comment: `:set nonumber` fixed the problem for me, not sure yet why. I need to read the docs anytime soon.